# Scanner never stops reading from keyboard

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

In the following code why it enters in a infinite loop? I thought it would shows me the first phrase I entered but he never stops reading from keyboard. 
1- Why?
2- How can I read only one time?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Type anything: ");

        while(scan.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("Token: " + scan.next());
        }

        System.out.println("-------------------------");
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Press ctrl-d to quit.  If you only want to read one thing then you could use `if` instead of `while`

Comment: I think you need to read the [JavaDocs for `Scanner#hasNext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext--), it doesn't work the way you think it should (ie, you're not actually in an infinite loop)

Comment: you will use while(scan.next()!=null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scanner is waiting for the "end of file" condition and i could only get this EOF condition by using the Scanner to read from a file. If you want to read the input only once and print it, then you could do as the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Type anything: ");
    System.out.println("Token: " + scan.next());
    System.out.println("-------------------------");
    scan.close();
}
```

You could also give it a condition to stop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Type anything: ");
    String input = scan.next();

    while(!input.equals("exit")){
        System.out.println("Token: " + input);
        System.out.println("\nType anything: ");
        input = scan.next();
    }
    scan.close();
}
```

What i used to read from a file:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    File file = new File("random_text_file.txt");

    try {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String word = scanner.next();
            System.out.println(word);
        }
        scanner.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext()

From the Scanner class documentation:

```
public boolean hasNext()
```

> Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input. This
>   method may block while waiting for input to scan. The scanner does not
>   advance past any input.

So, not only hasNext() returns a boolean but also waits for a key to be pressed (therefore making the call return true), which will be shown with a next() call.